# Quiz App случайная постановка вариантов ответов

Tags: android, массивы, json, android-studio, коллекции

купил в одного чудо "программиста" продвинутые курсы по созданию приложения QuizApp. В начале курса написал ему будут ли реализованы в курсе случайная расстановка вариантов ответов? Он ответил типа да все будет. Вот курс заканчивается и он мне говорит, что это не входило в планы курса и очень обвешивает код. 
Помогите реализовать уже это само в этом коде:

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class QuizModel implements Parcelable {
    String question;
    ArrayList<String> answers;
    int correctAnswer;
    String questinCategoryId;
    ArrayList<String> backgroundColors;

    public QuizModel (String question, ArrayList<String> answers, int correctAnswer, String questinCategoryId, ArrayList<String> backgroundColors) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.questinCategoryId = questinCategoryId;
        this.backgroundColors = backgroundColors;
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public int getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public String getQuestingCategoryId() {
        return questinCategoryId;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColors(ArrayList<String> backgroundColors) {
        this.backgroundColors = backgroundColors;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getBackgroundColors() {
        return backgroundColors;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(question);
        dest.writeList(answers);
        dest.writeInt(correctAnswer);
        dest.writeString(questinCategoryId);
        dest.writeList(backgroundColors);
    }

    protected QuizModel (Parcel in) {
        question = in.readString();
        in.readList(answers, QuizModel.class.getClassLoader());
        correctAnswer = in.readInt();
        questinCategoryId = in.readString();
        in.readList(backgroundColors, QuizModel.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static Creator<QuizModel> getCREATOR() {
        return CREATOR;
    }

    public static final Creator<QuizModel> CREATOR = new Creator<QuizModel>() {
        @Override
        public QuizModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new QuizModel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public QuizModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new QuizModel[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Вот ещё база данных вопросов с ответами

```
{
      "question": "Тривале перебування в умовах спеки викликало у людини спрагу. Сигналiзацiя вiд яких рецепторiв, перш за все, зумовила її розвиток? ",
      "answers": [
        " Натрiєвi рецептори гiпоталамусу",
        " Осморецептори печiнки",
        " Глюкорецептори гiпоталамусу",
        " Барорецептори дуги аорти",
        " Осморецептори гiпоталамусу"
      ],
      "correct_answer":4,
      "question_category":"1"
    },
    {
      "question": "Хворому з ревматоїдним артритом тривалий час вводили гiдрокортизон. У нього з’явилися гiперглiкемiя, полiурiя, глюкозурiя, спрага. Цi ускладнення лiкування є наслiдком активацiї такого процесу: ",
      "answers": [
        " Глiкогенолiз",
        " Глiкогенез",
        " Глiколiз",
        " Глюконеогенез",
        " Лiполiз"
      ],
      "correct_answer":3,
      "question_category":"1"
    },
```

Помогите пожалуйста, я только начинающий программист без какого либо технического образования. Только 3 месяц как начал учить программирование. На вас вся надежда. Хочу сделать тесты для студентов медиков что бы они лучше и удобнее учились сам недавно им был

В КОД ДОБАВЛЕНО ПРАВКИ С ПЕРВОГО ОТВЕТА

```
import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class QuizModel implements Parcelable {
    String question;
    ArrayList<String> answers;
    int correctAnswer;
    String questinCategoryId;
    ArrayList<String> backgroundColors;

    String trueAnswer;


    public QuizModel (String question, ArrayList<String> answers, int correctAnswer, String questinCategoryId, ArrayList<String> backgroundColors) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.questinCategoryId = questinCategoryId;
        this.backgroundColors = backgroundColors;

        this.trueAnswer = answers.get(correctAnswer);
    }

    public String getQuestion() {
        return question;
    }

    public void shuffleAnswers() {
        Collections.shuffle(answers);
    }

    public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
        return trueAnswer.equals(answer);
    }

    public int getCorrectAnswer() {
        return correctAnswer;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAnswers() {
        return answers;
    }

    public String getQuestingCategoryId() {
        return questinCategoryId;
    }

    public void setBackgroundColors(ArrayList<String> backgroundColors) {
        this.backgroundColors = backgroundColors;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getBackgroundColors() {
        return backgroundColors;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(question);
        dest.writeList(answers);
        dest.writeInt(correctAnswer);
        dest.writeString(questinCategoryId);
        dest.writeList(backgroundColors);
    }

    protected QuizModel (Parcel in) {
        question = in.readString();
        in.readList(answers, QuizModel.class.getClassLoader());
        correctAnswer = in.readInt();
        questinCategoryId = in.readString();
        in.readList(backgroundColors, QuizModel.class.getClassLoader());
    }

    public static Creator<QuizModel> getCREATOR() {
        return CREATOR;
    }

    public static final Creator<QuizModel> CREATOR = new Creator<QuizModel>() {
        @Override
        public QuizModel createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new QuizModel(source);
        }

        @Override
        public QuizModel[] newArray(int size) {
            return new QuizModel[size];
        }
    };

}
```

Comment: каким боком в тегах JavaScript, может быть все же Java? это совсем не одно и то же .. написание приложения-викторины хорошо описано в книгах П.Дейтела "Android для разработчиков" и Б.Филлипса "Android. Программирование для профессионалов", зачем покупать какие то курсы на общедоступные темы.

Comment: Так же здесь помогают решить конкретные проблемы с кодом, а не доделывают какие то продвинутые курсы за плюсики. Напишите в вопросе, что уже сделали для решения, что конкретно не получается или обращайтесь с заказами что то переделать на фриланс

Comment: Я знаю где что есть и без ваших указания я попросил исправить в конкретном коде порядок ответов 1. 2. 3. ... 5.. на случайный порядок 5. 3. 2. 4.1. и тд. то что написано в Дейтела в книге не понятно как задавать варианты вопросов ответов и тд там полностью закрыта база данных. Не хотите помогать пропустили этот вопрос и не пишите вообще ок?

Comment: Есть такой метод [`Collections.shuffle(list)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle(java.util.List%3C?%3E)) - он переставляет элементы списка в случайном порядке. Запомните правильный ответ в переменную, смешайте список этим методом и потом сравнивайте  правильный ответ с тем, что выберет юзер.

Comment: Спасибо в json ничего при этом менять не нужно?

Comment: @VladBulan не нужно

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать это в коде

Comment: @woesss Подскажите как реализовать Collections.shuffle(list) в моём коде пожалуйста нужно создавать отдельный класс или отдельный метод и в чём то другом это реализовать или так Collections.shuffle(ArrayList<String>)  answers ???

Comment: public static void shuffle (ArrayList<String> answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например так:

```
public class QuizModel implements Parcelable {
    String question;
    ArrayList<String> answers;
    int correctAnswer;
    String questinCategoryId;
    ArrayList<String> backgroundColors;
    // добавляем поле для правильного ответа
    String trueAnswer;

    public QuizModel (String question, ArrayList<String> answers, int correctAnswer, String questinCategoryId, ArrayList<String> backgroundColors) {
        this.question = question;
        this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
        this.answers = answers;
        this.questinCategoryId = questinCategoryId;
        this.backgroundColors = backgroundColors;
        // сохраняем правильный ответ
        this.trueAnswer = answers.get(correctAnswer);
    }

    // Когда нужно перемешать ответы вызываем этот метод
    // в остальном используем класс как раньше
    public void shuffleAnswers() {
        Collections.shuffle(answers);
        // исправляем номер правильного ответа
        correctAnswer = answers.indexOf(trueAnswer);
    }

    // этим методом сверяем ответ,
    // выбранный пользователем с правильным
    public boolean isCorrect(String answer) {
        return trueAnswer.equals(answer);
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!!!!  сейчас проверю работоспособность

Comment: Не работает или я что то не так делаю(((

Comment: Выражением "не работает" можно обозвать миллиард ситуаций - экстрасенсов здесь нет, поэтому не ленитесь описывать проблему в подробностях, если, конечно, хотите чтобы Вам помогли.

Comment: Скорее всего методы **shuffleAnswers** и **isCorrect** нигде в коде не используются и не инициализируются

Comment: Пробовал ещё вариант ответа который мне дали на английской версии сайта тоже ничего не вышло
[ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52247629/quiz-app-randomize-answers-on-android-studio)

Comment: А кто же за Вас будет их использовать и инициализировать? Или Вы хотите чтобы Вам доделали приложение и выложили готовое работающее со всеми хотелками? Тогда Вам на фриланс-биржу надо обращаться, а не сюда.

Comment: Скажите нужно ли заменить метод **getCorrectAnswer** на **isCorrect**??

Comment: `getCorrectAnswer` после перемешивания больше не верен - его нужно либо убрать и использовать для проверки `isCorrect`, либо изменить его реализацию на такую: `return answers.indexOf(trueAnswer);`

Comment: Обновил код в ответе - теперь можно использовать `getCorrectAnswer` как и раньше.

Comment: a `isCorrect` не использовать вовсе,?

Comment: Как хотите - можете убрать